Ctrl + Shift + B only affecting one edge
I am trying to create a plane with rounded edges.
The first ctrl + shift + b I use works perfectly:

However on following vertices I get this:

It seems to be only affecting one edge and failing to give a rounded effect.
Thank you in advance for any help explaining as to why that is.

Assuming you've already applied the scale in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale), I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

As @JohnEason said, make sure you have applied the scale. If that's already done, make sure there are no duplicate vertices: select all with A, then M > Merge by Distance.

Hi. Thanks a lot. Applying scale then merging by distance seems to have done the trick!
